# Detecting different events at up/down button in input number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to differentiate events up/down button of an input type number?

I read that there is a `change` event, but I would like to know if I could recognize different events on up/down button pressed.

I will be more clear:

```html
<input class="form-control" id="field" type="number" min="1" value="<VALUE>" onkeydown="return false">
```

```js
$("#field").change(function(e){ ... }
```

What I would like:

```
$("#field").onUpPressed(function(e){ ... }
$("#field").onDownPressed(function(e){ ... }
```

Comment: You can actually detect by previous value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971457/input-type-number-how-to-detect-if-value-was-incremented-or-decremented

Comment: Keyboard events in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: I think that i will use Mukuyuu solution.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no default events for this. To make it work you would need to store the previous value, which you could do with a `data` attribute, and then compare it to the new value, something like this:

```js
var $field = $("#field").on('input', function(e) {
  var newVal = parseInt($field.val(), 10);
  var oldVal = $field.data('old');
  
  console.log(newVal > oldVal ? 'up' : 'down');
  
  $field.data('old', newVal);
});

$field.data('old', $field.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="field" type="number" min="1" value="<VALUE>" onkeydown="return false">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory, this solution is more complete, i will store old value in data attribute for simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find to determine if a user is clicking in the type="number" field where the number is displayed vs. on the browser-generated "webkit-inner-spin-button / webkit-inner-spin-button" (where those styles aren't listed in the target exposed to JS) in Chrome 114 is to determine an offset:

```
let proceed = true
if (event.target.matches('input[type="number"]')) {
  var numberField = event.target
  var fieldBound = numberField.getBoundingClientRect()
  if (event.clientX > fieldBound.left + numberField.offsetWidth - 20) {
    proceed = false // Clicked on incrementor buttons
  }
}
// Take an action when the proceed = true
```

Just posting here for future reference.